# How to set the transparency of the area on my plot with matlab?

Tags: matlab, highlight, area, figure

I have this code:

```
figure(555555)
a1 = zeros(size(sigpow));
a1(ind) = max(sigpow);
highlight=area(a1);
set(highlight,'FaceColor', 'b');
hpatch = get(highlight, 'children');
set(hpatch, 'FaceAlpha',.10,'EdgeAlpha',.10);
hold on
plot(sigpow, 'k')
set(gca, 'xlim', [0 500])
```

which gives me this plot:
[image: plot]

I would like the blue area to have transparency (alpha 0.1) but my code doesn't work. What do I have wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Cheers!

EDIT: added an example of data

```
ind= [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
sigpow = [0.778;0.949;0.745;0.907;1.079;1.449;0.970;1.509;1.596;1.248]
```

Comment: Can you provide a working MWE? `set(get(h,'children'),'facealpha',.1)` works just fine.

Comment: I have just edited my question with a example of data.

Comment: Do you get some error message or just no transparency? Copy pasting your code works fine for me and I can set transparency to any value. I am using R2012b from an Ubuntu system.

Comment: what is the Matlab release/OS you are using?

Comment: Oh that is weird. I have Matlab2015a and Windows 7.

Comment: I actually get this message: Warning: MATLAB has disabled some advanced graphics rendering features by switching to software OpenGL. For more information, click here.

Comment: Ok, so I tried on another machine, with R2014a and it didn't work either (no OpenGL error message this time). I might try on a mac later on but I don't get why it doesn't work!!